# Trouble filtering out geoJSON undefined properties in .bindPopup

Tags: filter, geojson

I'm having a lot of trouble filtering a geoJson layer with sample data. This is a leaflet map showing locations where soil has been tested for lead.

Some locations have been sampled up to five times and others only one. I would like to only display a value if one exists. The GeoJson separates these samples as Lead_A to Lead_B. Some of the locations have a blank value for a Lead_# and others only have Lead_A.   Example:

```js
{
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":  [ -75.214921,39.997753 ]
   },
   "properties": {
   "Date":"7/19/2016",
   "Location":"Educare Learning Center ",
   "Address":"",
   "Lead_A":43,
   "Lead_B":73,
   "Lead_C":"18",
   "Lead_D":"866",
   "Lead_E":"88"
   }

// or 

{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -76.311359,40.04514 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "Date":"6/29/17",
    "Location":"Northwest Corridor Linear Park",
    "Address":"W Lemon St, Lancaster, PA 17603 ",
    "Lead_A":39
    }
```

This results in a popUp showing undefined for locations without a value. I would like to ideally filter out undefined, null and 0. But am trying undefined first.

[PopUp with undefined tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yv2V.png)

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you. Here's the code:

```js
function popUp(feature) {
  if(typeof feature.properties.Lead_B != undefined ||
    typeof feature.properties.Lead_C != undefined ||
    typeof feature.properties.Lead_D != undefined ||
    typeof feature.properties.Lead_E != undefined ||
  ) return true;

};

console.log(popUp);

L.geoJson(leadSample, {
  filter: popUp,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
               var pennLogo = new L.Icon({
                     iconUrl: 'images/pennLogo.png', //source, online search
                     iconSize: [25, 25],
                     iconAnchor: [12, 25],
                     popupAnchor: [0, -25]
               });
               return L.marker(latlng, {
                 icon: pennLogo,
                 tags: [undefined, null, 0]
               });
           }

}).bindPopup(function (layer) {

    return ( "Sample Date:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Date +
     "<dd>" + "<em>" + "Parts Per Million" + "</em>" + "</dd>" +
    ("<dd>" + "Sample A:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_A + "</dd>") +
   ("<dd>" + "Sample B:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_B + "</dd>")+
  ("<dd>" + "Sample C:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_C + "</dd>")+
 ("<dd>" + "Sample D:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_D + "</dd>")+
("<dd>" + "Sample E:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_E + "</dd>")
   );
 }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Got it!


}).bindPopup(function (layer) {

  var result = ( "Sample Date:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Date );
  result = result + ("<dd>" + "<em>" + "Parts Per Million" + "</em>" + "</dd>");
  result = result + ("<dd>" + "Sample A:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_A + "</dd>");

if(layer.feature.properties.Lead_B != undefined && layer.feature.properties.Lead_B != null && layer.feature.properties.Lead_B != 0)
 result = result + ("<dd>" + "Sample B:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_B + "</dd>");

 if(layer.feature.properties.Lead_C != undefined && layer.feature.properties.Lead_C != null && layer.feature.properties.Lead_C != 0)
  result = result + ("<dd>" + "Sample C:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_C + "</dd>");

  if(layer.feature.properties.Lead_D != undefined && layer.feature.properties.Lead_D != null && layer.feature.properties.Lead_D != 0)
   result = result + ("<dd>" + "Sample D:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_D + "</dd>");

   if(layer.feature.properties.Lead_E != undefined && layer.feature.properties.Lead_E != null && layer.feature.properties.Lead_E != 0)
    result = result + ("<dd>" + "Sample E:" + " " + layer.feature.properties.Lead_E + "</dd>");

return result;
 }).addTo(map);
```